# what should be my forecast data size if i got 2 years as initial data

Tags: machine-learning, forecasting, amazon-forecast

I got 2 years of training data for forecasting, usually i used 2 years data as training and 1 year data for forecasting. but recently i used Amazon forecast instance in that they have a constrain for giving forecast data size like

> initial data size should be 4 time's as forecast data size

Is there any best practices for this?